# How does data get into the General Purpose and other registers so that the CPU can use it for computing values?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

I know that registers serve as storage units for the CPU to access data from in order to execute an instruction. The assembly language for these instructions look something like ADD R2, R1, R3 essentially asking us to add contents in R1 and R3 and place it in R2. My question is, how does data get into the registers R1 and R3 so that the CPU can use those values to compute and store the result in R2? And if all registers get full, is data evicted to main memory from the registers using an LRU method similar to how data from caches are evicted?

Comment: By running instructions.  e.g. `mov R1, #5`.  Registers aren't a cache, they're manually managed; when a compiler runs out of regs for a function, it has to spill some values (by emitting store instructions for them with some destination, and later reload that data from mem.)

Comment: 1) There are other instructions for moving data from a memory address to a register, and vice versa. 2) No.  Registers are not evicted.  The registers are not part of the cache memory hierarchy from the perspective of the ISA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values get both into and out of registers using machine code instructions; machine code instructions can:

- Enter constants from the program into registers or memory

  - These are usually called load immediate or move
- Enter user input like keystrokes into registers or memory

  - some processors have input instructions, others load from memory mapped I/O
- Load data from memory, where long-lived variables & data structures are located
- Send register values to memory

  - to update data structures and other long-lived variables
- Send data to an output device (like a console)
- Compute new values given existing values

> And if all registers get full

It depends somewhat on what you mean by full.  In one sense, the registers always hold values, there's no notion in the ***CPU*** of free / busy architecturally specified registers <sub>(modulo some deep concepts on floating point & vector registers, and internal implementation details of OoO processors and register renaming)</sub>.  Similar is true for your hard drive.  It has exactly N gigabytes of storage, as far as the hardware is concerned, this number never grows or shrinks.

> And if all registers get full, is data evicted to main memory from the registers using an LRU method similar to how data from caches are evicted?

Yes, but virtually 100% under program control: the program knows what logical variables from our algorithms are in what CPU registers (and others in what memory locations), so there is a notion of an algorithm translated to assembly having either sufficient registers (leaving some unused) and also of wanting more registers than are available.  When that happens (desiring more than available), compiler writers and assembly programmers simply turn to memory for the overflow, writing machine code instructions to transfer data back & forth as needed.  Unimportant things can live in memory and suffer slower access times, allowing the CPU registers to be used as desired.

(In the hard drive analogy, all the bits are always there but not always in meaningful use.)

To be clear, the hardware has many LRU algorithms, but these generally surround cache architectures, including L1, L2, and TLB.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. What happens if the size of a variable exceeds the maximum size of the general purpose register? For example, storing a 33 bit value into a 32 bit register.

Comment: Overflow is the first answer.  The processors naturally support several widths of integers, and if you want variable length, that requires programming to deal with that, which involves checking for overflow and memory allocation.  There's no automatic mechanism to expand from one register to two when overflow happens.

Comment: @penguin99: Extended precision; store the high half in another register.  It's easy enough to look at actual compiler output for `int64_t` numbers on a 32-bit machine: https://godbolt.org/z/ee3zMP6x3 shows ARM64 using 64-bit registers vs. ARM (32-bit) having to use `adds` to set flags from the low half, and `adc` to do an add-with-carry on the high half, to propagate carry-out from the low half a carry-in into the high half.  (I picked ARM over x86 because its calling convention passes the first 4x 32-bit chunks of args in registers, so it didn't need extra load instructions.)

Comment: I appreciated the "modulo" comment. Stack/windowed register sets can also mark physically present register storage as not in use. With respect to hard drives, bad block support is standard; with SSDs there are tradeoffs between wear-levelling and used capacity. (DRAM can also have failures leading to reduced capacity, but hardware typically leaves managing bad memory to software.)

Answer (score 2):

General Purpose Registers are very similar in concept to variables in a programming language

```
R1 = 3
R3 = 5
R2 = R1 + R3
```

How you get those values into the registers is specific to the architecture and the value.  Some instruction sets have variable length instructions and can support any possible value

```
mov r1,0x12345678
```

Others can load half a register

```
lui r1,0x12340000
```

Not proper syntax for a real processor, but the ISA would allow for control
over the top half then you would follow it with an

```
ori r1,0x5678
```

And the end result is r1 = 0x12345678

Another solution is to load from a nearby location

```
ldr r1,hello
...
hello: .word 0x12345678
```

This would use pc-relative addressing, the assembler would do the math for you when it generates the instruction, but for example the actual instruction would be something like load from memory at the address of pc+16 into the register r1.

Registers are discrete and there is a fixed number of them, they are not cached or a fifo or anything like that.

From a programmer or compiler perspective, you can run out of them if you only have say 8 registers, and you are managing more than 8 data items, variables, addresses, etc.  AND you are using an architecture that requires
you to use registers for everything, then you would typically use the stack to temporarily store variables.

```
r1 = 0x12345678  (variable hello)
r2 = 0x55443366  (variable world)
...
I need another variable as the programmer I decide that I can live with out hello for a while
push {r1}
r1 = r2+r3     (variable foo)
str r1,[r4]    (the computed value was generated to store in memory)
foo is no longer neaded, but I need hello back
pop {r1}
```

Compilers that take a higher level language and generate a lower level language, often assembly language or machine code, will track variables through a function and select which registers to use when.  A particular
register may through the course of the execution of a function may hold several variables or addresses or other data...obviously only one thing
at a time.  The same thing we would do as humans by hand, but according to
an algorithm.